# Installing Python Module Six

Tags: python, six

I am running Python 2.7.9 on a Windows 8 machine. I've programmed for a long time (since the 60s), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to install the Six Module. I need a step-by-step set of instructions. Either help here or a suggested website would be helpful to this old man. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what problem are you experiencing when you try to install it?

Comment: It's actually a sheer lack of knowledge - I have downloaded six-1.9.0.tar.gz, but I'm not sure how to actually install it into Python - and the books/documents I have contain no explanation - I'm  from the really old days when you would just unpack straight into the program files -

Comment: Installing Python modules: https://docs.python.org/2/install/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. And I apologize to all for such a trivial question, but I needed some guidance.

Comment: All of this happens from the command line.
I found pip in 
cd C:\Python27\Scripts\

I then ran these three commands (if you run dateutil first, you might not need six)
pip install six
pip install python-dateutil
pip install pyparsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some computers where I don't have `pip` installed I usually do:

1. Extract the downloaded file
2. In the command line, where you extracted do `python setup.py install`
3. Module should now be installed
4. You can run `python` now
5. In the interactive interpreter do `import module_name`
6. If you get no errors, installation was a success