# My python console refuses to use the latest version of Six

Tags: python, six

I have some dependency problems in my python due to the console keep using 1.4.1 version of Six instead of 1.9.

So, on my python IDLE:

```
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.4.1'
```

But on my pip:

```
$ pip freeze
six==1.9.0
```

How can i force my IDLE to use the right version?

I tried uninstalling and installing with pip.

Output from python -v, then import six

```
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py
import six # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
dlopen("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so", 2);
import operator # dynamically loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.py
import StringIO # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.pyc
```

Comment: Do you have more than one python version installed? What does `pip -V`and `python -V` give you? You can use `python -v` to see from where python does import the library

Comment: $ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)


$ python -V
Python 2.7.9

Comment: Yes i have more than one python version installed

Comment: Can you also do `python -v` `import six`? That shows you from were it imports the module. Or does your problem only occur if you use IDLE?

Comment: it occurs in my python Console, regardless, but the version is correct in Pip

Comment: maybe reintall the whole python again?

Comment: If you call python with a lower case v (as in `python -v`) it shows you from where it does import your module. Execute python with `python -v` then import your module `>>> import six` and update your question with the output.

Comment: # /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py
import six # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
dlopen("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so", 2);

Comment: import operator # dynamically loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.py
import StringIO # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.pyc

Answer (score 1):

You are using a pip and a python from different versions, pip is from `/Library/[...]` while your python is from `/System/Library/[...]` You can use python from `/Library/[...]` or pip from `/System/Library/[...]`. You could also use use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). From the documentation:

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments. [...] It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either).

Comment: For the sake of not having to switch over to virtualenv (I do think its the best solution but I need a hack now) installing manually as Tom suggested seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Manually install *six* again ([Installing Python Module Six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388976/installing-python-module-six?rq=1)). Sometimes *pip* is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a left over six.pyo / six.pyc file in the current working directory or pythonpath directory.